# HTML5: Drag/drop on X-axis and without fade?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been looking for drag-and-drop examples/tutorials for HTML5, but all of them so far involve an object that fades as it's being dragged and without being constrained to any axis. I was wondering if it's possible to have the actual object itself be dragged as opposed to a ghost of it and whether I can constrain it to X or Y axis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, easily, by writing it yourself.

```
elem.onmousedown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var start = 0, diff = 0;
    if( e.pageX) start = e.pageX;
    else if( e.clientX) start = e.clientX;

    elem.style.position = 'relative';
    document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var end = 0;
        if( e.pageX) end = e.pageX;
        else if( e.clientX) end = e.clientX;

        diff = end-start;
        elem.style.left = diff+"px";
    };
    document.body.onmouseup = function() {
        // do something with the action here
        // elem has been moved by diff pixels in the X axis
        elem.style.position = 'static';
        document.body.onmousemove = document.body.onmouseup = null;
    };
}
```

Comment: Looks like `evt` ought to be `e`? As in `evt.pageX` and `evt.clientX`.

Comment: Would this work on a mobile device? like with the tap or swipe event?

Comment: With small adjustments, yes. You will need to use `touchstart/touchmove/touchend` events, and refer to `e.touches[0].pageX` instead.

Comment: Can't express how I feel when a simple-to-read code is posted as an answer, great snippet bro!

Comment: Hi @NiettheDarkAbsol do you probably have idea how to implement your answer to my case in here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813245/vue-js-how-to-make-object-drag-to-axis-x-and-y-only-using-native-drag-event-wi

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Event.movementX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX) to determine the difference in pointer position:

```js
const dragX = (evt) => {
  
  const el = evt.currentTarget;
  
  const move = (evt) => {
    el.style.left = `${el.offsetLeft + evt.movementX}px`;
  };
  
  const up = () => {
    removeEventListener("pointermove", move);
    removeEventListener("pointerup", up);
  };
  
  addEventListener("pointermove", move);
  addEventListener("pointerup", up);
};

// Use like:
const elDraggable = document.querySelector("#draggable");
elDraggable.addEventListener("pointerdown", dragX);
```

```css
#draggable {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
  user-select: none; /* prevent text selection */
  touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable">X axis draggable</div>
```