# How to constrain movement when using HTML5 native drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Various JavaScript libraries, such as jQuery UI, offer drag-and-drop interactions where you can [constrain the movement](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement) of the dragged element to a single axis, or within a particular area.

Is this sort of thing possible using the native [HTML5 drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_and_drop) API?

Comment: Linking to w3schools should be regarded as a felony.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5: Drag/drop on X-axis and without fade?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933513/html5-drag-drop-on-x-axis-and-without-fade)

Comment: I know this is an old post...but I solved this by creating a clone element on `dragstart`, hiding the original, and then setting the clone's position with the `dragover` event - where it can be constrained. Not much different from using `mousemove`. It was easier than completely rewriting drag and drop - which I'm sure many have.

Comment: hi @mseifert do you have the example code for this? i am also trying to do movement of dragging object that stick to axis x or y only

Comment: @AgnesPalit Yes. You can find the code at https://github.com/mseifert9/Javascript-Slideshow -- It is included as part of a slideshow. You can find the code in dragdrop.js + draggable.js + droppable.js. A full demo for the slideshow can be found at https://www.design.mseifert.com/index.php?topid=1&grade=Slideshow

Comment: @AgnesPalit Note that the framework for this library is completely custom - no outside dependencies exist. You will find supporting functions in mseifert.js  - It's been awhile since I worked with this code, so I apologize if I am missing something. This functionality is probably not particularly documented well. I apologize in advance for this. Good luck. If you find it useful, let me know. You can reach me through the contact page of my website. I won't have time to offer any support of it, however, due to my work schedule.

Comment: Thank you appreciate that. Do you maybe have idea how to solve the problem in here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813245/vue-js-how-to-make-object-drag-to-axis-x-and-y-only-using-native-drag-event-wi

Answer (score 11):

It's totally different!
The jQuery UI drag and drop make element move (with top and left CSS properties) in the page.

The native HTML5 drag and drop API only allow you to move a "ghost" of the draggable element (of course, you can hide the original element while dragging the ghost).

The API come with [a lot of event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_and_drop) but no, you can't constrain mouse position so you can't constrain to a single axis (cause the ghost follow the mouse position, even if the mouse leave the page (but event may probably stop operate)).

Comment: +1, I updated the link from W3Schools to MDN to avoid this becoming the topic of the question.

Comment: I never linked to W3schools, that was someone who edited my question. This site is lame.