# HTML Draggable Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> https://jsfiddle.net/yt1wvc76/

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="vl"> 
</div>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

In the following Jsfiddle is the draggable element. But what i wanted is that , users are only able to drag up and down and left to right ( once it placed on the middle , it will auto move the icon to the left/right side depending where did the user place (the green verticle line is an example to show)) .

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but have you reviewed the API? https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable

Comment: This post might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933513/html5-drag-drop-on-x-axis-and-without-fade