# Show element under finger that was selected upon touchstart on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mobile, touchstart

I am using jquery event detector for touchstart on an element in mobile devices.

Currently nothing is showing under the finger on mobile devices after touchstart fires (the border & background color are applied on the original element)- how do I get that element to show under the finger?

```js
$('body').on('touchstart', '.draggable', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log('TouchStart Fired');
  $(this).css({
    'border-color': '#55ba76'
  });
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

```css
.draggable { display: inline-block; border: 2px solid gold; }
```

```html
<div class="draggable" draggable="true">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" style="width: 5rem;">
    <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fill="#000" />
  </svg>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `dragggable` should be `draggable` :) 2 g's are enough. What means *"how do I get that element to show under the finger"*? ...as you move the finger around you want the element to follow??

Comment: In comparison, in desktop, when dragstart fires, a transparent copy of the element is shown under the mouse cursor as the cursor is dragged.  I want a similar thing to happen on mobile devices.

Comment: You mean, something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74169920/383904 :) No jQuery needed BTW.

Comment: No, they were asking to drag the actual object, I want to have a 'ghosted' copy of it under the finger during dragging